# SQL JOIN on three tables using a common table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have to make a join on 3 three table, the scheme is following:

```
 1. Request_Send table have: RequestID(FK),DonorID(FK),SendRequestID(PK)

 2. Donor table have Donor,ID(PK),Name,etc...

 3. Blood_Request table have RequestID(PK),etc...
```

Now I want to make join in which I could select some columns from Donor, some columns from Request. so how could I do this? 
my present query is:

```
   string show = "
SELECT Blood_Request.Date,Blood_Request.Time,Blood_Request.R_Name,R_Address,R_Phone 
FROM    Request_Send INNER JOIN 
        Blood_Request ON Blood_Request.RequestID=Request_Send.RequestID INNER JOIN 
        Donor ON Request_Send.DonorID=Donor.DonorID
Where D_Emial='" + Session["UserID"];
```

Please Help and thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the pb. Your query looks fine

Comment: i got exception which state that invalid column name "DonorID".

Comment: Please reformat the query string so it's not all one huge line.  It's hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is `Donor.DonorID=Request_Send.DonorID`

try this query your problem is solved.

```
string show ="
SELECT  Blood_Request.Date,Blood_Request.Time,Blood_Request.R_Name,R_Address,R_Phone 
FROM    Request_Send INNER JOIN 
        Blood_Request ON Blood_Request.RequestID=Request_Send.RequestID INNER JOIN 
        Donor ON Donor.DonorID=Request_Send.DonorID 
WHERE D_Emial='" + Session["UserID"] + "'";
```

Comment: got same exception: Invalid column name 'D_Emial'.

Comment: make sure you have a column D_Emial and use it tablename.D_Emial like that i think it should be D_Email not D_Emial

Comment: @denish Thanks alot there was spelling mistake of D_Email. Thanks for support.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide `talbe name` from where `D_Emial` will select data like

```
Where Request_Send.D_Emial ='something';
```

Comment: @miraj I can mark only one answer. I read your answer after issue was resolved, anyways thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

`Donor.DonorID` doesn't exist. Try `Donor.ID` in your join

Answer (score 0):

```
string show = "select bld_req.Date,bld_req.Time,bld_req.R_Name,R_Address,R_Phone FROM Request_Send req_snd INNER JOIN Blood_Request bld_req ON bld_req.RequestID=req_snd.RequestID INNER JOIN Donor dnr ON req_snd.DonorID=dnr.ID Where D_Emial='" + Session["UserID"] + "'";
```

please make sure D.Emial column is there in the table and call it like : tablename.D_Emial.